# Custom-flag for many off-topic comments - declined

Tags: discussion, comments, declined-flags

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23039574/2888561)

> Comment clean up. I guess you could remove the whole answer too (since people apparently hate it). - declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

There were a lot (like 15, now deleted) of off-topic comments, so I flagged for a moderator to delete them, and possibly delete my accepted answer since it wasn't received well by the community. Why was this declined?

Also, could somebody do something there? The voting patterns looked suspicious (sockpupet?), and it isn't exactly a "happy atmosphere".

Comment: Since it's your answer... couldn't you delete it yourself? Does the fact that the answer is accepted prevent you from deleting your own answer?

Comment: @mah It does exactly that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you think one or more of the comments should be deleted, you should flag that comment with a specific reason, or flag the comment thread (by way of a custom flag on your answer), explaining why. "Comment clean up" doesn't say much. Make the mods' job easy.

Comment: There was a debate in the comments. Isn't that enough to warrant a cleanup?

Comment: @bjb568: No.[‍](http://www.google.com)

Comment: Well, what is? There were over 15 (off-topic) comments before it got cleaned up.

Comment: @bjb568: Ah, you didn't tell us that. Was the cleanup a result of your flag, do you think? Were they removed before or after your flag?

Comment: After the flag was declined, then a little wait, then the meta-post. It was probably another mod noticing this post.

Comment: I assumed your question was around the remaining comments, @bjb568. You might want to amend your question. My answer stands, though - be detailed in your request. The lack of detail was probably why the flag was declined.

Comment: In any case, the off-topic comments where there at the time of reviewing, so that doesn't explain it fully. Unless the mods are *really* lazy to not even bother checking…

Comment: Mods are lazy, like everyone should be. They get [some unexpectedly large number of] flags a day. Make their job easy.

Comment: Siiiigh… Ok, I'll try to be clearer next time (hopefully there won't be one).

Answer (score 9):

I processed the flag and I don't recall my reasoning for declining the flag. It could have been a mistake but in looking at the text of your flag it seems like you are asking two things:

> Comment clean up.

This part of your flag was correct.  There were multiple off-topic and non-constructive comments on both answers so they were removed.

> I guess you could remove the whole answer too (since people apparently hate it).

Is this a request to delete the answer?  Is this just a comment complaining about the downvotes to it?  What exactly is this part of the flag asking?

It wasn't exactly clear from the second part what you were requesting so this is why the flag was probably declined.  When you use the "Other" flag for us to act on, please be clear what you expect from it.

Comment: I wasn't sure what I was asking, myself :) I didn't know whether it should be deleted or not. I'll try to be clearer.